# Can we disable Search on List Views

Tags: 2013, list, search

I have a generic Custom Sharepoint List in SP2013. On this list i have a column called Document State where i store current state of the document such as In review, Archived, Published.

My requirement is to only display items to end users of document state -eq Published. Which i can easily do that using Views and User Audience. But can i restrict search on items within that list whose Document State -eq to Archived.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

> But can i restrict search on items within that list whose Document State -eq to Archived.

Search is security trimmed, so four options come to mind:

- Break inheritance on individual documents and set permissions for who can see non-Published items. (Typically with a workflow.)
- Create a folder for non-Published documents with permissions for only the editors. Move the document to the top level of the library when they are published, either using drag/drop or a workflow.
- Create multiple libraries and use the Content Organizer feature to move items based on metadata.
- Create two libraries, only grant permissions to the non-Published library to the editors, and use a Content Query or Search web part to roll up the results. Manually, or by workflow, move documents to the Published library when ready.

Answer (score 1):

The list globally has a setting under (List Settings > advanced > allow items to be in search results (yes / no)) This makes them searchable at the site / list level.

If you want to "hide" the "find an item" search box from a view you can either change the style to something other than "Default" because the default view is the only one that has the "find an item" search box.

With that said if you like the default view you can remove the "find an item" search box for a default styled view by editing the web part and unchecking the "display search box" from the Miscellanious section of the web part settings menu.

[image]

If you really want your archived items to not be searchable you would have to make some sort of workflow to copy the items to another list where the search is turned off for that list. (also deleting the items from the main list after they are moved).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest and simplest way to do this is creating two lists:

1. Non-archived documents.
2. Archived documents.

Then, create a workflow on the *Non-archived documents* list like this:

```
Wait for Document State to equal Archived
      Copy item in this list to Archived documents
```

Finally, set up *Archived documents*'s permissions so that only corresponding users will be able to access.